# ASP.NET MVC 3 - Partial View displayling as new page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

I have had look at a few post already here but I am none the wiser. I tried my first example of Ajax but to no avail. The Partial View is loaded into a separate page as opposed to changing the dom element in the current page.

> The pupose is by clicking on the Refresh link in updates the "Last Activity Date" value of the current row only.

Please if there is an easy well of doing this can you also let me know?

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<RegistrationManager.User>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Users";
}

@section scripts {
    @Content.Script(Url, "jquery-unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")
}
<h2>Users</h2>


<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Email Address</th>
        <th>Given Names</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>Last Activity Date</th>
        <th>Refresh</th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    string selectedRow = "";
    if (ViewBag.UserId != null && item.UserId == ViewBag.UserId)  
    {  
        selectedRow = "selectedrow";  
    }  
    <tr class="@selectedRow" valign="top">
       <td>
            @item.UserName
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Profile.GivenNames
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.Profile.Surname
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="@String.Format("LastActivityDate{0}", item.UserId)">@Html.Partial("_DateOnlyPartialView", item.LastActivityDate)</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Refresh", "Refresh",
                         new { UserId = item.UserId },
                         new AjaxOptions {
                             UpdateTargetId = "LastActivityDate" + item.UserId,
                             InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                             HttpMethod = "GET"                                 
                        })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Conrtoller:

```
public PartialViewResult Refresh(Guid? UserId)
{
    User user = _db.Users.Find(UserId);
    user.RefreshLastActivityDate();
    return PartialView("_DateOnlyPartialView", user.LastActivityDate);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you included/referenced all the necessary javascript files?

If you have UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled then you'll need:

1. jQuery
2. jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js

if you also use client side validation, you'll need;

1. jquery.validate.js
2. jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js

These files can all be found when you create a new MVC3 project.

Comment: View Source shows:<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> So what am I missing?

Comment: Is there any javascript errors? Do the files actually exist in the Scripts folder? Try using the non -min versions of the javascript files. I have seen corrupt versions of them in the MVC 3 project

Comment: No JavaScript errors. Yes they exists. I have not changed anything from the standard ASP.NET MVC3 project. I have added the scripts you mentioned. Not sure about the first one mentioned though.
@section scripts {
    @Content.Script(Url, "jquery-unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")
    @Content.Script(Url, "jquery.validate.js ")
    @Content.Script(Url, "jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")
}

Comment: Problem resolved spelling mistake of the first file. Thank you.